# Struggling with rJava and dependent packages in Rstudio Mac M1. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:

Tags: java, r, rjava

I'm really struggling with rJava. I have a new machine (Mac M1) and am running r code from an older project on an old intel Mac, and it isn't working at all. I am not especially familiar or confident with this, or using the terminal so please bare this in mind when answering :)

The error message I am getting is:

```
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
I think one issue is that if I run
$/usr/libexec/java_home /usr/libexec/java_home /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

It thinks java is not in the right place?

I tried to rectify this by doing:
`JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home` 
but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Grateful for any advice

Comment: First let's check the Java version(s) you have installed. Could you please post the output of the following command?   /usr/libexec/java_home -V

Comment: Also, you showed the error message, but what produced it? What is the particular command or action that reproduces the error?

Comment: Apologies, I ended up downloading Azul https://www.azul.com/core-post-download/?endpoint=zulu&uuid=cf6e06ec-c897-4b5a-9859-e1c547ff5864, which rectified the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was rectified by downloading Azul https://www.azul.com/core-post-download/?endpoint=zulu&uuid=cf6e06ec-c897-4b5a-9859-e1c547ff5864